# Why is GedankEN used in ‘Er hatte einen interessanten Gedanken’?

Tags: adjective

Why is it Gedank**en** in "Er hatte einen interessanten Gedanken"?

I thought the noun should be Gedank**e** because it is a *maskulin singular noun* with *Akk. Adjektiv* applied in that sentence obviously, but my Kursbuch shows as Gedank**en**?! Really gets me confused.

May I check with you if my thought is valid and my Kursbuch is wrong?

Comment: What do you think does the Akkusative form of "Gedanke" look like? Please avoid slang and write standard English or German in questions (unless that is the subject of the question).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the dative case of "Kunde" have an "n"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/70344/why-does-the-dative-case-of-kunde-have-an-n) See also https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11225/weak-masculine-nouns and https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53382/dative-single-noun-bankautomaten/.

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't answerable with declension table.

Comment: @RDBury One doesn't usually need declension tables for German nouns; the case endings for neuter, feminine and plural nouns are completely predictable. This is what makes weak nouns so surprising when they are first encountered. It's just that native speakers mostly aren't aware of the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

The noun *der Gedanke* follows the weak noun declination. It's also called *n-Deklination* because all forms but nominative singular end in -(e)n. Genitive singular may end in *-(e)n* or *-(e)ns*, that's a bit wonky with those nouns. Both are okay but usually one or the other is more common.

Most masculine nouns ending in *-e* follow this pattern. You should know about *der Junge* already. But there's some more patterns and also exceptions. So for masculine nouns, you not only have to learn the definite article and the plural but also the genitive singular. As that one gives away whether the declination is strong or weak. And also whether the -n or -ns genitive is more common.

- der Zug, des Zuges, Züge
- der Junge, des Jungen, Jungen
- der Gedanke, des Gedankens, Gedanken

At least there's one rule: only masculine nouns may follow this declination scheme. There's exactly one exception to this. It's the noun *das Herz* which has **two** different declination schemes depending on whether you mean the organ or courage. The latter follows a modified n-Deklination.

Comment: many thanks for your kind clarifications and special / exceptional word examples shared for explanation. The declension of Gedanke needs my special attention for 4 cases applied. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

What are you talking about? It's

---

1. Nom. sg.: der Gedanke
2. Gen. sg.: des Gedankens
3. Dat. sg.: dem Gedanken
4. Akk. sg.: den Gedanken

---

1. Nom. pl.: die Gedanken
2. Gen. pl.: der Gedanken
3. Dat. pl.: den Gedanken
4. Akk. pl.: die Gedanken

---

Akkusativ, männlich, Einzahl: "den Gedanken". Nothing to see here, carry on.

Comment: Hi Ingmar, Thanks for your reply. My German textbook shows der Gedanke is Nom. sg. and die Gedanken as its plural form. In that sentence I shared, Gedanke is the Object of hatte, so it follows Akk. Thus, it should be einen interessanten Gedanke, not Gedanken. Hope i made my question clear here.

Comment: I am afraid you are wrong. "Gedanken" can either mean 1.) sg. dat. or 2.) sg. acc. or 3.) plural (all cases). So, yes, it's acc. sing. but that means "den Gedanken". 
"Gedanke" is only used for the nominative singular.

Comment: I see, many thanks for your kind explanation.